# Creating a label for each entry in a list, but the last entry does not get a label created

Tags: python, list, button, tkinter

I decided to make a program that would let you create a 'build' for Fallout 4, a game I play a decent amount and was something to do while I wait for something to be released. Currently, I just had them in a `.txt` file so I decided to add a 'splitting' function that would split them up into each build. This works fine but it doesn't seem to create a label for the last entry in the list (of lists). When I print the list all the lists are stored correctly but the label for the final entry in the list is not created.

```py
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.builds=[]
        self.split()

    def split(self):
        currentBuild=[]
        with open('FO4 Builds.txt', 'r') as f:       # opens the txt file I've been using and reads the data from it
            for line in f:
                if line == "\n":                     # used to distinguish between different builds
                    self.builds.append(currentBuild) # adds currentBuild to the list self.builds
                    currentBuild=[]                  # clears currentBuild for further use
                else:
                    print('line =',line)
                    currentBuild.append(line)
        print(self.builds[-1])                       # me testing if the last build was being read or not (it is)
        
        for build in self.builds:
            Label(self,text=build[0]).grid()         # Creates a label with the name of the build, currently only for testing purposes but the last label does not appear

main_screen = Tk()
setup_screen(main_screen,"Fallout 4 Character Creator", 600, 600) # one of my custom functions, imported from another file but not included here
app = Application(main_screen)
main_screen.mainloop()
```

Here's an example of the `FO4 Builds.txt` layout:

```
Heavy gunner
Outfit:
Stats:
2. Perk
3. Perk
4. ....

Gunslinger
Outfit:
Stats:
2. Perk
3. Perk
4. ....
```

Comment: Can you include an expected vs what you got output, in form of picture or something?

Comment: Sure thing, here's a picture of the window: [link](https://imgur.com/a/wrlY3hA) and a pastebin for the full 'self.builds': [link](https://pastebin.com/nx2kL2hR) and one with only the 'keys' (the names of each build) [link](https://pastebin.com/HmdQumWh)

Comment: Actually it's a good thing you asked because it seems like the error is actually with the way I'm reading from the text file, because the last entry is actually never added.

Comment: Oh i see, then hopefully you can fix it better than any of us

Comment: If I had to guess what it was I would say it's the `if` statement that checks if the string is equal to a new line not ending off the last list. Not entirely sure on a solution though.

Comment: Could be, its hard for us to understand whats going on, as youve designed it from your POV with your idea.

Comment: Well I was right about it being the if statement, because adding another new line at the end of the file fixes it, but still a little confused as the file has to end with 2 empty lines in order to recognize the last entry

Comment: Could be because of `\n` not sure

Comment: I bet you are on windows and a new line followed by nothing is `\r`. Once you add the second empty line the entire thing becomes `\r\n\r`. You should make a tag/token to be used as a break between different builds. Not all OS's treat new lines the same. However they would all treat (ex) "::build::" the same after you `.strip()` the line.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I'm not sure why `.strip()` would be needed. Wouldn't you just be able to check if `line` is equal to `'::build::'`, and if it is then append `currentBuild` to `self.builds`?

Comment: After testing I figured out why you'd use `.strip()`, since just doing `if line=='::build::':` doesn't work as it the line technically includes the new line character

Comment: It is because what you see the *last empty line* is not `\n`, but EOF (end of file).  So the statement `if line == '\n':` will not be executed for the last set of build.  You need to check whether `currentBuild` contains items after the for loop, if it contains items, append it to `self.builds`.